# starting fcgiwrap

Tags: boot

I have been having problems with starting fcgiwrap as socket and service(ill give some info on that if anyone wants to take a crack at that), so i was looking for a diffrent way to start it.So from https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/fcgiwrap/

i found this line `sudo -u www-data /etc/init.d/fcgiwrap` to add into rc.local, but  i got this error `rc.local[268]: Usage: /etc/init.d/fcgiwrap {start|stop|force-stop|restart|force-reload|status}`
I would like to know what is the correct way to call it as `sudo -u www-data /etc/init.d/fcgiwrap {start}` didnt work.

Didnt find a perfect tag for this so boot will do

Comment: Something like this maybe : `sudo -u www-data /etc/init.d/fcgiwrap start`, `start` without `{}`

Comment: interactive authentication required is what i got when tried this a while ago but didnt have time to comment im guessing the line will work now if i get around the authentification

Comment: Please take note that using `/etc/rc.local` has limitations due to [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). We have seen many problems here on this site using it. Following the recommendation of the developers from **systemd** you should avoid using it.